# Java cannot find symbol createobjectbuilder

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I’m having difficulty compiling this code.  I'm using Intellij-IDEA.

I downloaded the [JSON Processing API jar](https://jsonp.java.net/download.html).  I also added the path to the JAR in the project's environment variables.  This did not resolve the error.

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;

…

JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
```

The error is

```
Error:(104, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createObjectBuilder()
  location: class javax.json.Json
```

Comment: Use maven to resolve jar dependencies if you are using intellij, it makes it extremely easy

Comment: *"I also tried explicitly putting the path to the JAR in the project environment variables."* You just tried?

Comment: You said you tried .. and failed? Then how should IDEA know where the JAR is? And how have you  tried it?

Comment: @Tom - I added the path.  The path did not resolve the error.

Comment: You added the path ... to what? And where?

Comment: @Tom - I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the json jar to the Module's Dependencies?  If you right click on your project and select Open Module Settings you can then select your module and clicking on the Dependencies tab and then the + on the bottom you can add the json dependency.  As it sounds like you are not using Maven, you'll want to select Java Library and browse to your json jar.

[image]

Comment: Yea, I tried that prior to posting the question.  I ended up using Maven, which still required classpath modification.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had an errant import statement.

Below did NOT work:

```
import io.vertx.core.json.Json;
```

After I removed the above import and added this one, everything was ok:

```
import javax.json.Json;
```

My reference / dependency (gradle flavored):

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api
    compile group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.1.4'
```

Reference is from:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.1.4